# Constructing a List of DataFrames in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to dynamically construct a List of DataFrames in Rcpp and I'm wondering what the most efficient way to do this would be?

I have read that the push_back function for Rcpp list's is very inefficient (copy on each push?) hence preallocation should be must faster, however it does not seem to be much faster in my problem. This is a basic example of how I'm doing it

```
List exampleList(someLimit);
std::vector <double> one;
std::vector <std::string> two;

for(int i = 0; i < someLimit; i++) {
    //vector One and Two are dynamically filled elsewhere
    exampleList[i] = DataFrame::create(_["a"] = one, _["b"] = two,  _["stringsAsFactors"] = false));
    one.clear();
    two.clear();
}
```

Is this the proper way to pre-allocate?   Is there a faster way to do this to avoid copies? Are there perhaps STL containers that could directly wrap to a List of DataFrames?

Thank you.

Comment: Its going to have to convert the `std::vector` and `std::string` objects to `NumericVector` and `CharacterVector` objects so if you could create them that way to start with that might save some time.  Benchmark it to be sure.

Comment: DataFrame objects are just list object with an extra attribute, and the current code can have issues when pushed by many (think "dozens" or more) objects, or large ones . So I would recommend to just create lists of lists. You can always postprocess via `as.data.frame()` once back in R.